# intente arreglar pero no pude no me levanta el tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'mainSecurity': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iusuarioRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iUsuarioRepository' defined in com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iUsuarioRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iUsuarioRepository.findbyNombreUsuario(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iUsuarioRepository.findbyNombreUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyNombreUsuario' found for type 'Usuario'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iUsuarioRepository.findbyNombreUsuario(java.lang.String)! No property 'findbyNombreUsuario' found for type 'Usuario'
'''

```
       ` #   package com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security;   #
    
    import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Service.UserDetailsImpl;
    import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.jwt.JwtEntryPoint;
    import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.jwt.JwtTokenFilter;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
    
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class MainSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl;
        @Autowired
        JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;
    
        @Bean
        public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() {
            return new JwtTokenFilter();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                    .and() 
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
            http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManager();
        }
    
        
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    '''
    `  
    
         #        package com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.jwt;
    
    import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Service.UserDetailsImpl;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
    
    
    public class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        private final static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);
        
        @Autowired
        JwtProvider jwtProvider;
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsImpl userDetailsImpl;
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{
            String token = getToken(request);
            if(token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)){
                String nombreUsuario = jwtProvider.getNombreUsuarioFromToken(token);
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsImpl.loadUserByUsername(nombreUsuario);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("fallo el metodo doFilterInternal");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    
       private String getToken(HttpServletRequest request){
       String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
       if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer"))
           return header.replace("Bearer", "");
       return null;
       }
    }

'''


   

## Título ##


# package com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Service;

import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Entity.Rol;
import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Enums.RolNombre;
import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iRolRepository;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RolService {
    @Autowired
    iRolRepository irolRepository;
    public Optional<Rol> getByRolNombre(RolNombre rolNombre){
        return irolRepository.findByRolNombre(rolNombre);
        
    }
     public void save(Rol rol){
         irolRepository.save(rol);
     }       
}


##
package com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Service;

import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Entity.Usuario;
import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Repository.iUsuarioRepository;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UsuarioService {
   @Autowired 
   iUsuarioRepository iusuarioRepository;
   
   public Optional<Usuario> getByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario){
       return iusuarioRepository.findByNombreUsuario(nombreUsuario);
   }
   public boolean existsByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario){
       return iusuarioRepository.existsByNombreUsuario(nombreUsuario);
   }
   public boolean existsByEmail(String Email){
       return iusuarioRepository.existsByEmail(Email);
   }
   public void save(Usuario usuario){
       iusuarioRepository.save(usuario);
   }
}


##
package com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Service;

import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Entity.Usuario;
import com.portfolio.cristaldo.Security.Entity.UsuarioPrincipal;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

   

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nombreUsuario) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.getByNombreUsuario(nombreUsuario).get();
        return UsuarioPrincipal.build(usuario);
        
    }

       
}
```

Comment: "No property 'findbyNombreUsuario' found for type 'Usuario'" <- sin ver codigo.. imposible saber tu problema.. pero ahi dice que falta algo.. falta?

Comment: De todo el código que adjuntas no pusiste lo que es realmente importante y donde estaba el error: Tu interface `iUsuarioRepository`. Está claro que no tiene el método que estás llamando `findbyNombreUsuario`.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez holaa... dime cual código tengo que adjuntar amigo y lo hago porque se nota que entendiste el error y me gustaría resolverlo desde ya gracias

Comment: @Diego el código de la interfaz iUsuarioRepository.